# Múltiples callbacks en evento JS

Tags: javascript, callback

Tengo un formulario con dos campos de entrada

```
<form action="file.js" method="post" class="FormData">
    <div>
        <p>Year</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="Year"></input>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="Tvshow"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button class="btn">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Por un lado, el campo Año obtendrá el año elegido por el usuario para mostrar cualquier programa de televisión y el campo de programa de televisión guardará el nombre del programa de televisión para mostrarlo en base a la solicitud de api de moviedb.

Este es mi código javascript:

```
const callbackYear = Year_User => 
{
    Year_User(Year);
}

const callbackTvshow = show => 
{
  show(name)
}

const getData = () => {
    const button = document.querySelector(".button");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const Form = document.querySelector(".FormData");
        const Year = new FormData(Form).get("Year");
        const name = new FormData(Form).get("Tvshow");
        callbackYear(Year);
        callbackTvshow(name);
    });
}

callbackYear((Year_User) => 
{
  console.log(Year_User);
})

callbackTvshow((show) => 
{
  console.log(show);
})
```

Básicamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer es obtener ambos datos (año y nombre de Tvshow) con dos callbacks (Year_User y show) para hacer una condición entre ellas.

Algo como esto:

```
//Ejemplo
 callbackYear((Year_User) => 
 {
   if(Year_User!=undefined)
   {
     callbackTvshow((Tvshow) => 
     {
       //Code


     })
   }
 })
```

Tal vez podría ser más claro ahora con este ejemplo.

Comment: Has probado a debuggear? Te sale algún error en la consola?

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas hacer y tampoco entiendo tus `callback`. ¿Dónde defines la función `Year_User` y `show`?

Comment: Hola Mauricio, lo que intento hacer es tener dos callbacks distintas para el año y el nombre de la serie, para que posteriormente pueda hacer una declaración entre ellas, ahora actualizo el post.